# Approximately locate an image within another

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, scikit-image

I have this image of the world : 
[image: World map here]
And this image of europe :
[image: Europe 1919]
What technique could I use to approximately locate the image of europe within the world map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template matching is a technique for finding similar images within larger images, but it requires the template to be of the same size as in the sub-image. In this example [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) was used, but it can also be done using [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-features-detection-plot-template-py).

```py
import cv2
from imageio import imread

img = imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIsWn.png", pilmode="L") 
template = imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkNeW.png", pilmode="L")

# threshold images for equal colours
img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
template = cv2.threshold(template, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

aspect_ratio = template.shape[1] / template.shape[0]

# estimate the width and compute the height based on the aspect ratio
w = 380
h = int(w / aspect_ratio)

# resize the template to match the sub-image as best as possible
template = cv2.resize(template, (w, h))

result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

cv2.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, 127, 3)

cv2.imwrite("europe_bounding_box.png", img)
```

Result:

[image: europe_bounding_box.png]

Although this example uses a predetermined estimated width, it is also possible to test a range of possible widths and determine which value results in the best match.

Comment: I implemented your solution for an unknown width with great results, see : https://github.com/cadoman/mapisto/tree/master/notebooks
Can you update your answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: @cadoman yes, I updated my answer with more explanation about the template size and included a link to your notebook. If I missed something important, feel free to suggest another edit.